# How to combine array that has same key?

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I get this array, but I want to show me KEY and all subitem of that KEY bellow, I dont want every time to repear a key, I need that key shows only one and all others entity that has same key under this one.

```
 array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["A"]=>
        string(2) "Test1"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(1) {
        ["A"]=>
        string(2) "Test1"
      }
    }
```

I want something like this:

```
 array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["A"]=>
       string(2) "Test1", 
        string(2) "Test2"
      }
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the following:

```
$return = array_merge_recursive($array, ...);
```

in your case:

```
$return = array_merge_recursive($array[0], $array[1]);
```

but I am guessing you'll want a more dynamic solution, I will draft that up now.

```
$return = call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive', $array);
```

Comment: But it is in same array, i have tried to merge it with empty array but doesnt work, and also I have tried to merge it with it self

Comment: look at the 'in your case part'

Comment: @user3042036 please check out the latter 2 snippets as they can both be used in your situation, the final one being dynamically adapted to any amount of array elements.